# Select rows meeting certain criteria in a "grouped by" statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I select (in MSAccess) all the columns (A-G) corresponding to the row with minimum value in column "G" for records grouped by "Name"? Here's a sample table

```
ID Name A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1 CHRIS 30  -99 -99 0   0   0   239
2 CHRIS 30  -99 -99 0   0   0   233
3 CHRIS 30  -99 -99 0   0   0   120
4 CHRIS 30  -99 -99 0   0   0   41
5 CHRIS 40  1012    130 20  20  0   55
6 KEITH 55  1012    230 175 150 50  178
7 KEITH 55  1012    250 125 175 100 22
8 KEITH 35  1012    270 25  25  0   76
9 KEITH 40  1012    320 100 100 0   90
```

in which the result would be:

```
CHRIS   30  -99 -99 0   0   0   41
```

and

```
KEITH   55  1012    250 125 175 100 22
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a unique ID?

Comment: You mean the record "Name"?, each Name may have a number associated with it...

Comment: I mean does your table look like `1 Chris, 2 Chris ...6 Keith`

Comment: not really, but those could be added I guess...

Comment: Life is going to be a lot more difficult without a unique id, unless you do not have many records.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21496/discussion-between-oliver-amundsen-and-remou)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL isn't too difficult if there is only one row with the minimum `G` value for each `Name`, or if you are willing to accept more than one row for a `Name` when the minimum `G` value is repeated.  Use a subquery which returns the minimum `G` per `Name` and join that to your sample table.

```
SELECT
    smp.Name,
    smp.A,
    smp.B,
    smp.C,
    smp.D,
    smp.E,
    smp.F,
    smp.G
FROM
    SampleTable AS smp
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            [Name],
            Min(G) AS MinOfG
        FROM SampleTable
        GROUP BY [Name]
    ) AS sub
    ON
            (smp.Name = sub.Name)
        AND (smp.G = sub.MinOfG);
```

However it's more challenging if you require only a single row per `Name` even when the minimum `G` is repeated for that `Name`.  In that case, you can include another subquery level which returns the minimum `ID` for each combination of `Name` plus minimum `G`.  And use the subquery's `Name` and minimum `ID` to join back to your sample table.

```
SELECT
    smp.Name,
    smp.A,
    smp.B,
    smp.C,
    smp.D,
    smp.E,
    smp.F,
    smp.G
FROM
    SampleTable AS smp
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            sub1.Name,
            CLng(
                DMin(
                    "ID",
                    "SampleTable",
                    "[Name]='" & [sub1].[Name]
                        & "' AND G=" & [sub1].[MinOfG]
                    )
                ) AS MinOfID
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    [Name],
                    Min(G) AS MinOfG
                FROM SampleTable
                GROUP BY [Name]
            ) AS sub1
    ) AS sub2
    ON
            (smp.Name = sub2.Name)
        AND (smp.ID = sub2.MinOfID);
```

I tested both queries in Access 2007 with your sample data saved in a table named `SampleTable`.  And both returned the result set you asked for.

Note I used `CLng()` in the second query to cast the value returned by `DMin()` as `Long`.  Without `CLng()`, the `MinOfG` value was returned as `String` which wouldn't work in the join.

Comment: I used the first one because G columns have no duplicates for single "names". thanks again..

Answer (score 3):

See if this will lead you in the right direction. It would be better if you had a UserId versus name to JOIN on, because you don't want to end up with duplicates in the join.

```
SELECT
    Table1.Name 
    , Table1.A
    , Table1.B
    , Table1.G
FROM
    Table1 
INNER JOIN Table1 as Table2 ON Table2.Name = Table1.Name
GROUP BY Table1.Name , Table1.A, Table1.B, Table1.G
HAVING Table1.G = MIN(Table2.G)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost with Users U and Users U2...Say that my table is called Table1. How should I write the sentence you proposed?

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect your question. The U was just an alias of the table. Seeing it this way should help visualize better.

Comment: @JasonHeine It seems that Oliver has now added an ID.

Comment: I get an error message saying: "You tried to execute a query that does not include ... 'Table1.G = MIN(Table2.G)' as part of an aggregate function"